# ¿Estoy haciendo bien este código?

Tags: c++, condiciones, math

soy nueva en la programación, soy de un nivel muy básico espero que mi pregunta no sea muy tonta.

Estoy haciendo un código que toma dos números del 1 al 5 y dice que si ambos son primos, haga el siguiente código:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int
main ()
{
  
 int n1, n2;
 
  cout << "Ingrese un número del 1 al 5: \n";
  cin >> n1;
  cout << "\nIngrese un número del 1 al 5:\n";
  cin >> n2;
  do
  {
      if ((n1 %1 == 0 && n1 %1 == 0) && (n1 < 5 || n1 > 1 || n2 < 5 || n2 > 1))
  }
  
  while(1<= n1 && n2)
  
  if(0==2)
  {
      cout<<"\nAmbos son números primos";

  }
  else 
{
    cout<<"\nUno o ninguno de los números son primos o Ingreso un número que no está dentro del rango ";
}
  
    return 0;

}
```

Pero me dice el siguiente error y no lo entiendo, no sé si alguien me podría ayudar:

```
    main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:23:3: error: expected primary-expression before ‘}’ token
   }
   ^
main.cpp:27:3: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘if’
   if(0==2)
   ^~
```

Comment: El while debe terminar con `;` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/do-while-statement-cpp?view=msvc-160

Comment: Además de lo anterior, esto `if ((n1 %1 == 0 && n1 %1 == 0) && (n1 < 5 || n1 > 1 || n2 < 5 || n2 > 1))` no parece tener mucho grado de aplicabilidad dentro del `do` es decir ¿luego de todas esas comparaciones que se hará?

Comment: Esto da siempre falso: if(0==2)... luego de esto: while(1<= n1 && n2)  pones un ; el if dentro del do que se supone que hace? y los valores siempre son iguales? Hay muchos errores de logica...

Comment: Pues los únicos números primos del 1 al 5 son: 2, 3 y 5; así que puedes comparar con eso `n1` y `n2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código tiene, al menos, dos errores:

1. Un `if` sin código:

   ```
    if ((n1 %1 == 0 && n1 %1 == 0) && (n1 < 5 || n1 > 1 || n2 < 5 || n2 > 1))
   ```

   Si la condición del `if` fuese verdadera ... ¿Qué código se va a ejecutar? No has indicado ningún código y eso no es legal en el lenguaje C++

   La estructura del `if` sería

   ```
    if (condicion) codigo
    if (condicion) { codigo }
   ```
2. Un bucle `do-while` termina con punto y coma

   ```
   do
   {
       // ...
   }
   while(1<= n1 && n2);
   //                 ^ importante
   ```

Luego, aparte de eso, el programa no cumple con los requisitos, veamos.

Si tomamos el caso particular de números del 1 al 5, la condición para que sean primos es la siguiente:

```
bool primo = (numero != 4);
```

Dado que el resto de números se consideran primos: 1, 2, 3, 5.

así que el código se podría simplificar bastante:

```
while (true)
{
  cout << "Ingrese un número del 1 al 5: \n";
  cin >> n1;
  cout << "\nIngrese un número del 1 al 5:\n";
  cin >> n2;

  if (n1 != 4 && n2 != 4)
    cout << "Ambos números son primos\n";
    break;
  else
    cout << "Al menos uno de los dos números no es primo\n";
}
```

Si ya quieres garantizar que el usuario te ha hecho caso y ha introducido un número en el rango de valores esperados tendrás que hacer alguna comprobación adicional